# SQL query optimisation / Re-factor

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to optimise the following query.

The following query works fine but I used **where** and **from** condition many times.

**Query:**

```
    SELECT st_astext(st_line_substring(
                                     (SELECT st_linemerge(geom)
                                      FROM geom_line
                                      WHERE i_project = $id),
                                     (SELECT $bas/st_length(geom)
                                      FROM geom_line
                                      WHERE i_project = $id),
                                     (SELECT $son/st_length(geom)
                                      FROM geom_line
                                      WHERE i_project = $id) ))
FROM geom_line
WHERE i_project = $id;
```

Regards. !

Comment: Yes. This query looks wrong even. How many geom_line records do I get with one i_project? One or many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tink you can try thus

```
SELECT st_astext(st_line_substring(  st_linemerge(geom)  ,
                                  $bas/st_length(geom),
                                 $son/st_length(geom) ))
FROM geom_line
WHERE i_project = $id;
```